# Django: login page is not authenticating when the user exists in the database

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am very new to this so sorry if it bleedingly obvious. The sign_up method in my views works perfectly, it adds a user to the database with all the correct credentials. However, the `log_in` does not. It seems to keep telling me that I have invalid login details (the printed statement in `views.log_in`) and when I try to log in that way with the superuser I get:

> Reverse for WSGIRequest: POST '/login/' not found

```
Internal Server Error: /login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\UoB_MSc_Computer_Science\MSc_Dissertation\Django_Project\accounts\views.py", line 33, in log_in
    return redirect(request, 'html/menu.html')
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 58, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 149, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Coding_Environments\Interpreter_35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 636, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/login/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/login/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[23/Jul/2018 20:52:43] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92646
```

It could be something to do with the forms?

Thanks very much for the help.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import SignUpForm



def sign_up(request):
    form = SignUpForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print("form invalid")
    return render(request, 'html/sign_up.html', {'form': form})


def log_in(request):
    print("here?")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print("got to the login request")
        if user is not None:
            print("getting close...")
            if user.is_active:
                print("it worked")
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(request, 'html/menu.html')
        else:
            print("invalid login details. User: " + username + ", Pass: " + password)
            return render(request, 'html/login.html')
    else:
        print("login didnt work")
        return render(request, 'html/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.sign_up, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.log_in, name='login')
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from accounts.models import User, UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User as user_auth


class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    bot_protect = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                                  validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')


class LogInForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = user_auth
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^menu', include('menu.urls')),
    url(r'^source_plag/', include('source_plag.urls')),
]
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for Django_Project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!9cd!8exs*4_=jg$a5)si*f09_9a+qygxhgily9cfg#_1nc%b6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com', 'localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'source_plag',
    'menu',
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Django_Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Django_Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
                'NAME': 'plagiarism_db',
                'USER': 'postgres',
                'PASSWORD': 'Maddie1$%^',
                'HOST': 'localhost',
                'PORT': '5432',
                    }
         }



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-uk'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.models import User, UserProfile

admin.site.register(User)
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TextLeak Sign-in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/accounts.css" %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/datalegreya" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>t|1e|2x|2t|1l|2e|3a|2k|3</h1>
<h2>Welcome to TextLeak Plagiarism Detector!</h2>
<h3>Please input your login details: </h3>
        {% if form.errors %}
        <P>Incorrect details!</P>
        {% endif %}
<div class="container1">
    <form id="login" method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
        <input type="button" name="signup" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:8000/signup/';" value="Sign-up">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked around at all the similar problems on SO but still cannot find the problem with my code.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You seem to have a custom user model. You should therefore set the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) setting. Otherwise, the default authentication backend will not use your custom model. After that, you should drop your db and remake migrations.

Comment: ... but none of those are related to your problem, which as the error says is to do with URLs. However you have not shown the complete error message, so it is impossible to tell where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the main point was that it was not finding the user in the database even though they were there - it was giving me an invalid login not an error. The error i was referring to came from trying the admin credentials in the same login form - i have put the error up now if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback shows that this error is not from a failed login, but from what you do on a successful login. You call the redirect function, but you pass it the request anda template name, which are the parameters for the tender function.

You should fix this by passing a path, or a URL name:

```
return redirect("index")
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, you solved 1 out of 2 problems so firstly thank you for that :) it seems to work when logging in a superuser but not a regular user, do you know why? i have registered a user correctly but unable to log them in

Comment: How are you defining what is a super user? You don't have a field for that in your model. In fact, I can't see how this could working at all, since you don't have an is_active field either, hash the passwords, inherit from AbstractBaseUser, or set AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to your user model.